# Python: How do you convert an image array to a custom font?

Tags: python, fonts

To make my question more understandable, I'm looking for a way to make a custom font in Python. I have an image array of my handwriting (each image is a character) that I wanted to turn into a font (preferably .ttf or .otf). If you know any modules that can do this or ways to do this, please tell me. Any answer is appreciated.